# Extracting multiple xml trees from a mixed content document

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I'm trying to use Python to extract multiple XML elements from a mixed-content document. The use case is an email that contains email text but also contains multiple XML trees.

Here's the example document:

```
Email text email text email text email text.

email signature email signature.

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>

Email text email text email text email text.

email signature email signature.

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>

Email text email text email text email text.

email signature email signature.

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>

Email text email text email text email text.

email signature email signature.
```

I want to extract the XML trees so they can be parsed by an XML parser in a for loop. I've perfected parsing the XML, and if I take one of the XML trees and parse it directly, it works llike a charm.

Any advise on how to extract the XML trees? This example is over-simplified as well, the email text and signatures are different in each example that I have, so the only reliable text to key on is the beginning and ending of the XML tree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Question**: I want to extract the XML trees so they can be parsed by an XML parser

**Do you realy want to get multiple XML Trees?**
I want to suggest to make **one** XML Tree with multiple `<book` subelements.

Nevertheless, here is what you want:

```
xml_tag = "<?xml"
catalog_end_tag = "</catalog>"

xml_tree = []
_xml = False
with open('test/Mixed_email_xml') as fh:
    while True:
        line = fh.readline()
        if not line: break

        if line.find(xml_tag) >=0:
            _xml = True

        if _xml:
            xml_tree.append(line)

        if line.find(catalog_end_tag) >=0:
            _xml = False

for line in xml_tree:
    print('{}'.format(line[:-1]))
```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way:

```
import re
from lxml import etree

with open('email.txt') as f:
    catalogs = ''.join(re.findall('<catalog.*?</catalog>', f.read(), re.S))
    root = etree.fromstring('<?xml version="1.0"?><root>{}</root>'.format(catalogs))
```

Then you could just use `root.iter('book')` to iterate over all the `book` nodes.

Answer (score 1):

With the help from another very smart developer, this code solves my problem.

```
tr1 = "<?xml"
str2 = "</catalog>"
i = 0
ii = 0
tracker = []
final_ls = []

for c in data:
    for char in str1:
        if data[i + ii] == char:
            if ii == len(str1) - 1:
                tracker.append(i)
            ii += 1
    i += 1
    ii = 0

for xml in tracker:
    ii = 0
    i = xml
    for c in data[i:]:
        if ii == len(str2):
            break
        ii = 0
        for char in str2:
            if data[i + ii] == char:
                if ii == len(str2) - 1:
                    final_ls.append(data[xml:i + ii])
                    ii += 1
                else:
                    ii += 1
        i += 1

for ls in final_ls:
    print(ls)
```

Comment: I really want to complete this in a simpler and cleaner way, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

my first idea is use the str methods to split the all the text like

```
t = txt.split(r'<?xml version="1.0"?>')

results = [item.split("</catalog>")[0] + "</catalog>" for item in t if item.startswith("\n<catalog>")]
for i in results:
    print(i)
```

just as code, split by the obvious delimiter.